# Autocomplet JQuery widget not working on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

I have an issue with the autocomplete widget from jquery(https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). When I start the local development server, everything works fine, the widget works perfect, but when I pull the branch on the test server( I have a special testing server that is a copy of the main server), it's not working(and travis tests from github are failing)
I don't know if is relevant or not, but I am working with Mojolicious

```
$(function() {
    var pages = [];
    % foreach (@$pages) {
        pages.push('<%= $_->{title} %>');
        pages.push('<%= $_->{id} %>');
    % }
    $("input[name=page_title]").autocomplete({
        source: pages,
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3
      });
    });
```

How can I figure it out?

Comment: What is the final source code? Are you getting any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: @ChrisG: "A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://jquery.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032." -> this is the only warning that i get at the beginning of the final source code